# How does a GTM differ from GA or FA as far as android is concerned?

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm only talking about this in a event tracking perspective. I understand GTM is a tool for managing Firebase/Google Analytics, AppsFlyer etc. I have been told GTM is of great benefits when it comes to tracking events on websites and how they are not required to make code level changes for every individual event in the page,  by adding a tag in let's say the header of the page or something.

Eliminating repetitive event track codes at the action of buttons or whatsoever and also the need of developers for minor tracking based changes.

Let us assume I have an application with just one screen and 4 buttons(A,B,C,D) in it.
I have put analytics event tracking codes under the click action of the buttons using Google/Firebase Analytics.

Why should I use GTM and how is it going to benefit in the above scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Actually when it comes to apps it is actually Firebase that manages GTM (i.e. you use Firebase to push events to GTM that then can be used in other tags).

Thus, if all you want to use is Firebase Analytics then you do not profit from GTM at all.

However if you want to use additional tags (Google Analytics, marketing tags and similar) then your advantage is that (to some extent at least) you can additional tags without rebuilding your app.